# Android broadcast receiver not working with intent receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

Hi I developed one small android application in which I am using one activity one intent service and one broadcast receiver. 
So my code looks like :

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity {

    private ResultReceiver resultReciver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_);
        Log.i("***************************88", "inside activity on create");

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.nilkash.broadcast.receiver");
        resultReciver = new ResultReceiver();
        registerReceiver(resultReciver, filter);
        //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(resultReciver, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
        startService(intent);

    }

    public class ResultReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        public ResultReceiver()
        {

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("**********************", "inside broadcast receiver: ");
        }

    }

}
```

And  intent service

```
public class ExampleService extends IntentService{


    public ExampleService(String value)
    {
        super(value);
    }

    public ExampleService()
    {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("********************************", "inside intetn reciver: ");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("com.nilkash.broadcast.receiver");
        //broadcastIntent.putExtra("value", "nilkash");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

In manifest file I define service. 
So my problem is that I start service from activity and its working fine. From service on intent receive I sent one broadcast receiver but it not listening inside my broadcast receiver.

Am i doing some thing wrong? Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error: `sendBroadcast(intent);`. Should be another intent object (`broadcastIntent`).

Comment: Hi esebtsov thank you for help;But I am not getting your solution. Can you please explain it more.

Comment: In your service method `onHandleIntent` you send broadcast by calling:`sendBroadcast(intent);`. But should call `sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);` There `intent` is intent which was used for starting service.